# How to Configure DHCP to Assign a Specific IP Address to a MAC Address in IOS

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, dhcp

How can I manually configure DHCP to give a certain IP address to a specific MAC address in Cisco Packet Tracer?  I know how to configure DHCP, but I don't know the configuration which is used give an IP address to a specific MAC.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

Simple:

```
ip dhcp pool (hostname)
   host (ip address) (netmask)
   hardware-address (mac)
```